# Having issues with Launching Eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04 i keep getting this issue

Tags: eclipse

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'helloworld'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'trial'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Which Eclipse version, which Java version? Do you have any additional plug-ins installed? Please show a screenshot (showing the error and the files of both projects) and add an example of how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: java version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)


Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200